# Android: how to change number format to Hindi-format (Eastern Arabic numerals) for the whole application?

Tags: android, localization, number-formatting

Like so Eastern Arabic numerals {٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩}
I use this method to change App language but it does not work completely to show the Hindi Numbers

```
    Locale Language = new Locale("ar");    
    Resources resources = context.getResources();    
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();   
    Configuration conf = resources.getConfiguration();   
    conf.locale= Language;   
    Language.setDefault(Language);   
    conf.setLayoutDirection(Language);   
    resources.updateConfiguration(conf, displayMetrics);
```

Comment: What does completely means? Can you describe the problem you have?

Comment: the problem is how to make the Hindi number format as default,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like with everything related to i18n, the app must be written in a way that permits localization.

For example, `Integer.toString(i)` will always use digits 0-9. To get localized numerals you must use `String.format("%d", i)` or `NumberFormat.getInstance().format(i)` instead.